# Assign array strings to some links

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

In my current code I have two countries that display a popup when clicked and in the popup you can see some links. Links are mapped correctly but my problem is with the links name.

The way I wrote the code so far, is good for displaying the name of link for a country with one link. I'm calling the link name with `ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.linkName` in the code below:

```
chart.openPopup("<strong>" + ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.country + "</strong>" + ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.link.map(url => '<br><a href="' + encodeURI(url) + '">' + ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.linkName  + '</a>').join(""));
```

How can I write `ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.linkName` in order to display both names for a country with 2 links? I want `Name 2` assigned for `https://www.example2.com` and `Name 3` assigned for `https://www.example3.com`.

If anyone can help me regarding this issue, I would greatly appreciate it.

```js
am4core.ready(function () {

  // Themes begin
  am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
  // Themes end

  // Create map instance
  let chart = am4core.create("map", am4maps.MapChart);

  // Responsiveness enabled
  chart.responsive.enabled = true;

  // Set map definition
  chart.geodata = am4geodata_worldHigh;

  // Set projection
  chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();

  // Zoom control
  chart.zoomControl = new am4maps.ZoomControl();

  let homeButton = new am4core.Button();
  homeButton.events.on("hit", function () {
    chart.goHome();
  });

  homeButton.icon = new am4core.Sprite();
  homeButton.padding(7, 5, 7, 5);
  homeButton.width = 30;
  homeButton.icon.path = "M16,8 L14,8 L14,16 L10,16 L10,10 L6,10 L6,16 L2,16 L2,8 L0,8 L8,0 L16,8 Z M16,8";
  homeButton.marginBottom = 10;
  homeButton.parent = chart.zoomControl;
  homeButton.insertBefore(chart.zoomControl.plusButton);

  // Center on the groups by default
  chart.homeZoomLevel = 3.5;
  chart.homeGeoPoint = {
    longitude: 10,
    latitude: 54
  };

  let groupData = [{
    "color": chart.colors.getIndex(0),
    "data": [{
      "country": "Germany",
      "id": "DE",
      "link": ["https://www.example1.com"],
      "linkName": ["Name 1"]
    }, {
      "country": "France",
      "id": "FR",
      "link": ["https://www.example2.com", "https://www.example3.com"],
      "linkName": ["Name 2", "Name 3"]
    }]
  }];

  // This array will be populated with country IDs to exclude from the world series
  let excludedCountries = ["AQ"];

  // Create a series for each group, and populate the above array
  groupData.forEach(function (group) {
    let series = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
    series.name = group.name;
    series.useGeodata = true;
    let includedCountries = [];

    group.data.forEach(function (country) {
      includedCountries.push(country.id);
      excludedCountries.push(country.id);
    });

    let polygonTemplate = series.mapPolygons.template;
      polygonTemplate.tooltipHTML = '<b>{country}</b>';
      polygonTemplate.events.on("hit", function (ev) {
        chart.closeAllPopups();
        // Map countries and link encoding
        // How to write -> ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.linkName <- in order to display Name 2 and Name 3 separately ?
        chart.openPopup("<strong>" + ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.country + "</strong>" + ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.link.map(url => '<br><a href="' + encodeURI(url) + '">' + ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.linkName  + '</a>').join(""));
    });

    series.include = includedCountries;

    series.fill = am4core.color(group.color);
    series.setStateOnChildren = true;
    series.calculateVisualCenter = true;
    series.tooltip.label.interactionsEnabled = false; //disable tooltip click
    series.tooltip.keepTargetHover = true;


    // Country shape properties & behaviors
    let mapPolygonTemplate = series.mapPolygons.template;
    mapPolygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color("#c4a5e8");
    mapPolygonTemplate.fillOpacity = 0.8;
    mapPolygonTemplate.nonScalingStroke = true;
    mapPolygonTemplate.tooltipPosition = "fixed";

    mapPolygonTemplate.events.on("over", function (event) {
      series.mapPolygons.each(function (mapPolygon) {
        mapPolygon.isHover = false;
      })
      event.target.isHover = false;
      event.target.isHover = true;
    })

    mapPolygonTemplate.events.on("out", function (event) {
      series.mapPolygons.each(function (mapPolygon) {
        mapPolygon.isHover = false;
      })

    })

    // States  
    let hoverState = mapPolygonTemplate.states.create("hover");
    hoverState.properties.fill = am4core.color("#FFCC00");

    series.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(group.data));

  });

  // The rest of the world.
  let worldSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
  let worldSeriesName = "world";
  worldSeries.name = worldSeriesName;
  worldSeries.useGeodata = true;
  worldSeries.exclude = excludedCountries;
  worldSeries.fillOpacity = 0.5;
  worldSeries.hiddenInLegend = true;
  worldSeries.mapPolygons.template.nonScalingStroke = true;


});
```

```css
  body {
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  }

  #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  #map a,
  b {
    cursor: pointer;
    color:  #003399;
    text-align: center;
  }

  #map a:hover {
    color: #023432;
  }

  .ampopup-content {
    /* width: 40%; */
    text-align: center;
  }

  .ampopup-header {
    background-color: #99000d !important;
  }

  .ampopup-close {
    filter: invert(1);
  }

  .ampopup-inside {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }

  .ampopup-inside a {
    color: #28a86c !important;
  }

  .ampopup-inside a:hover {
    color: #023432 !important;
  }

  .ampopup-curtain {
    display: block !important;
    background-color: rgba(7, 22, 51, 0.7) !important;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Countries popup with links</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts for loading AmCharts Map -->
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/maps.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/geodata/worldHigh.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom2.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `index` provided by the `.map` to access the nth element in the
`linkName` array.

```js
let polygonTemplate = series.mapPolygons.template;
polygonTemplate.tooltipHTML = '<b>{country}</b>';
polygonTemplate.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  chart.closeAllPopups();
  const {
    links,
    linkNames,
    country
  } = ev.target.dataItem.dataContext;

  // Map countries and link encoding
  const popupContent = `<strong>${country}</strong><br />
  ${
  links.map((url,urlIndex)=>`<a href="${encodeURI(url)}">${linkNames[urlIndex]}</a>`).join('')
  }`;
  chart.openPopup(popupContent);
});
```

Comment: is there a way to avoid jQuery code in your example to keep it strictly JavaScript?

Comment: @JustMe there is no jquery in my code, the `$` is the syntax of the [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Sorry, the `$` confused me a little

Comment: @JustMe added a link in the previous comments talking about template literals. It helps to avoid the string concatanation and messing with the quotes.